# node.js exec on raspberry pi to make a picture with gphoto2

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

After making one picture my camera is stuck. I simply tried to use the exec command, because it seems to be the easiest approach. I use a canon eos 400d, raspberry pi model B and node.js version 0.10.28 . Thanks for any help!

```
var Camera = function(){
}

Camera.prototype = {
  sys: require('sys'),
  exec: require('child_process').exec
}

Camera.prototype.takePicture = function(imageCount, nextImagePosition, callback){
  this.exec("gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.jpg' ",     
  function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: What is `this`? Can you post the whole code?

Comment: I updated the code, but as i described before, i'm able to take one picture. after that my camera is stuck and i can't take any further pictures. when i run the command on the commandline, there is no such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case that somebody has the same problem the solution was to update gphoto2 with the following script: https://github.com/gonzalo/gphoto2-updater